# What is good replacement for MS Paint on Mac OSX

Tags: osx, pixel-graphics

What is a good replacement for MS Paint on  Mac OSX? I am interested in both free and paid solutions. Ideally it would be as simple and as similar to MS Paint as possible. I am not interested in tools like Gimp etc.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Answer (score 1):

An exact replacement of paint is the [Paintbrush](http://paintbrush.sourceforge.net/)

As per their description,

> Paintbrush is a simple paint program for Mac OS X, reminiscent of
>   Microsoft Paint and Apple’s own now-defunct MacPaint. It provides
>   users with a means to make simple images quickly, something that has
>   been noticeably absent from the Mac for years

some other tools

[SketchBook](https://www.sketchbook.com/desktop)

[Paint DS](http://www.rdsisemore.com/paintds/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

[Patina](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/patina/id942568098?mt=12) was built [specifically](http://www.patinaapp.com) to answer the need for an MS Paint equivalent on the Mac.  Patina was just released on the Mac App Store and is currently being offered for free.